# Invalid operands for multiplication in SCSS using node-sass

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I'm trying to test a implementation of bezier cubic curves with Sass following a [post](http://thesassway.com/advanced/cubic-bezier-representation-in-sass) but i'm having an error throw when compiling the sass file using node-sass, this is the error:

```
{
  "formatted": "Error: invalid operands for multiplication\n        
       on line 192 of public/scss/components/_bezier.scss\n>>
       if($x1 == 1, 90deg, 0 - atan(($y1 - 0) / ($x1)) * 1rad),\n   ------------------------------------^\n",
  "message": "invalid operands for multiplication",
  "column": 37,
  "line": 192,
  "file": "/Users/msantamaria/Documents/dev/presonal_projects/sass-bezier/public/scss/components/_bezier.scss",
  "status": 1
}
```

the problem is exactly on this line:

```
background: linear-gradient(
if($x1 == 1, 90deg, 0 - atan(($y1 - 0) / ($x1)) * 1rad),
//more params...
```

doing a bit of testing I find I'm running the function with a value of `0.something` for `$x1` and if I change the value to a integer the function works and the error doesn't shows up.
I think it has something to do with the way node-sass does it vs ruby sass.

[This is the codepen](http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/eqCvo) for it if you want to mess around and see the entire code.

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

*This was marked as duplicate but the question and answer related are not the same and don't provide any information or possible answer to my original concern.*

*The problem here is not about the function not being defined, since as I mentioned, when the value is 1 the mixin does work.*

Comment: Codepen compiles Sass with Compass, which provides the functions you're trying to use: http://compass-style.org/index/functions/.  The "invalid operands" error is because you're trying to multiply a string and a number together.

Comment: Yes, your question is a duplicate.  Search for the property 'foo' in the compiled output (compiled with LibSass): http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/63743b7a8d8610c00d48.  You can't use a function if it doesn't exist, I don't know else to say at this point other than stop using LibSass if you're unable to get the functions you need.

Comment: Then why is it working for 1 as $x1 and not for 0.3 for instance? Is there a particular reason the integer will work and the decimal not?

Comment: It's not failing on those values, it's failing to get the results of functions that aren't part of the standard library.  If you can provide a minimal example that proves otherwise, update your question to contain that information.

Comment: Sorry, I get it now, the 1 value is entering the if and so is setting 90deg. That sassmeister link with the foo property was really really helpful thanks a lot!